# Can you set up a delay after which old questions that are downvoted would get deleted?

Tags: feature-request, bug

Thanks to [SE's policies on deleting old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/175062) that have an downvote, an old question can be easily deleted without the intervention of anyone when it gets a downvote and the vote count goes to -1.

The users are also not even notified when the question is downvoted, even 10k+ users who can see the deleted question would have no idea who deleted it, can you add an delay to the deletion of old questions or atleast notify the user before the delete?

P.S:-This could be *abused* by anyone to delete old questions that do not have any upvotes, as a single downvote will kill it.

Comment: What is the use of keeping old question, if they don't have an answer anyway?

Comment: Bringing attention to material that should be removed will only serve to create conflict, arguments, debate, and disagreement. The solution to this is to edit questions that don't conform to the guidelines and improve them. If a question hasn't been improved by the time it's eligible for deletion, then it's obviously not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO 30 days is more than enough time. If the OP cares about his question he will definitely visit the site to see the progress of his question. He will also see the downvote and possible comments about it. So if he cares about his question he will try to improve it, edit it, the question will pop on top, people will see it, and if he did a good job in improving his question, the question will undoubtedly be upvoted and no longer eligible for deletion.

> P.S:-This could be abused by anyone to delete old question that do
>   have any upvote as a single downvote will kill it.

I have noticed that good questions always receive at least one upvote. So we should not be really concerned of loosing good question by this policy.